# How would I join and insert data to the VO from 2 different database

Tags: java

Before I only have 1 SQL query where all of the column fields located in only 1 database. But now I need to move the StudentAccess to a different database. I need to join both of the database record and insert it to my VO object.

Database 1:
Select STUD_ID_NR, STUD_NM, STUD_LOG_ID
from Student

Database 2:
SELECT STUD_LOG_ID, STUD_LOG_ID from StudentAccess
WHERE logFlag= true

The STUD_LOG_ID will be the identifier for both of the table to join them.

This is my current code before that store data from only 1 Database

Class 1:

```
try
{
    conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement()
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(StudentQuery);
    

    List<StudentVO> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<StudentVO>;
    
    if(null != rs)
     {
      while(rsv.next())
       {
         StudentVO validStudent = StudentsMapper.mapToVo(rs.getString(STUD_ID_NR), 
         rs.getString(STUD_NM), rs.getString(STUD_LOG_ID));

         if(validStudents != null)
          {
            listOfStudents.add(validstudent);
          }
      
    StudentStore.setAllStudents(listOfStudents);
}
```

If the data's are coming from two database. how would I Still insert the STUD_LOG_IN_ID of the student to the VO if their STUD_LOG_ID had a match?

Let's assume that we can call both of the database in this class.

```
try
{
    conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement()
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(StudentQuery);
    rs2 = stmt.executeQuery(StudentAccessQuery);

    List<StudentVO> listOfStudents = new ArrayList<StudentVO>;
    
            if(null != rs2)
             {
              while(rsv.next())
               {
               }
             }
    
            if(null != rs)
             {
              while(rsv.next())
               {
               }
        
            StudentStore.setAllStudents(listOfStudents);
    }
```

I'm quite confused on how will I do it. should I add both record in an arraylist first then use the contain?

My VO contains the STUD_ID_NR,STUD_NM,STUD_LOG_IN_ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sugesstion

I don't know which SQL you are using but will suggest you to make your desired result set using a single query itself. It will be much easier to handle the data .

`Connection` to a DB is always costly , try to minimize the no of connections .It is for good practise.

### Alternative

In java your approach is correct , however as per my understanding from the post `contains` may not work as 2 result sets may have different values.
If that is not the case you can use `contains`.

Below is an example without using `contains`.Here I have assumed 2nd result set may have multiple values as per each `LOGIN_ID`.

```
 List<StudentVO> listFromDb1 = new ArrayList<StudentVO>;
 List<StudentVO> listFromDb2 = new ArrayList<StudentVO>;
    
if(rs2 != null){
    while(rsv.next())
    {
        // listFromDb1
        //add result set from db1
    }
}

if(rs!=null){
    while(rsv.next())
    {
        // listFromDb2
        //add result set from db2
    }
}

List<StudentVO> finalList = new ArrayList<StudentVO>();

// considering listFromDb1 is your main dataset
for(StudentVO student : listFromDb1){
     //boolean true =listFromDb2.stream().filter(s-> s.equals(student.getSTUD_LOG_IN_ID())).findAny().isPresent();
     for(StudentVO student2  : listFromDb2){
         if(student.getSTUD_LOG_IN_ID().equals(student2.getSTUD_LOG_IN_ID())){
             
            //set the student values in new object and then add it to final list
             StudentVO tempStu= new StudentVO(student,student2.getSTUD_LOG_IN_ID()); //it is just an example.
             
             finalList.add(tempStu); 
            
             //use break here if 2nd resultset doesnot hold multiple log in id for same student;
         }
     }
}

StudentStore.setAllStudents(finalList);
```

Comment: If I will use 2 database should I also add connection and statement for the other database?

 ``conn = getDataSource().getConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt2 = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(StudentQuery);
    rs = stmt2.executeQuery(StudentQuery);`

Comment: At least you will need to create 2 ` connection` for each DB. Then the rest is identical whatever you will do for 1 connection you need to do same for the other